# How much TNT do I need to blow up Mars' moon Deimos?

Tags: space, weapon-mass-destruction, nuclear-weapons

Specifically I want to blow it up into lots of little bits, not just nudge it towards the planet so that it de-orbits on its own.

Comment: Are we literally talking trinitrotoluene, or explosive force in megatons?

Comment: Hopefully the latter - a TNT stockpile on the surface of the planet won't blow it up into small pieces seeing as explosions typically follow the path of least resistance, and you can't get more 'least resistant' than space.

Comment: @Halfthawed, then even a nuke on the surface would go preferably in space

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica I'd advise something more akin to a Death Star as long as we're going with the 'turn moons to dust' model.

Answer (score 7):

The gravitational binding energy of a body is how much energy is required to accelerate every atom in random directions up to escape velocity.  The gravitational binding energy of Deimos is about 1.4e16 joules.  One megaton is about 4.1e15 joules.  So Deimos would take a blast of about 3-4 megatons to obliterate.

This is probably an underestimate as you will likely be unable to deliver that energy evenly.  Any energy spent accelerating an atom above Deimos escape velocity is wasted.